How can I set extraHTTPHeaders within a Playwright test
In my test I need to make an API request that requires a bearer token. I have managed to do this with a static, pre-defined token, but I need to get a new token each time via a GET request and this needs to be done at the time the test runs. I can get this token, but can't work out how to set it in the extraHTTPHeaders. This is what I currently have:
Spec:
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { ApiRequests } = require('../api/apiRequests.js');

test.use({
    extraHTTPHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer token'
    }
})

test("My Test", async({ page }) => {
    const apiReq = new ApiRequests(page)
    await apiReq.postRequest('apiURL', requestBody, 200)
})

apiRequests.js:
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

export class ApiRequests {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page    
    }

    async postRequest(url, requestBody, statusCode) {
        const response = await this.page.request.post(url, {  
            data: requestBody
            
        }) 

        expect(response.status()).toBe(statusCode)
        return(response)
    }
}

So I want to be able to do what the test.use block is doing within the test block.

Related: How to do a POST Request with PlayWright, How to add custom headers in Playwright

I seem to have found the solution. I am now setting the token when the request is made:
apiRequests.js:
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

export class ApiRequests {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page    
    }

    async postRequest(url, requestBody, statusCode) {
        const response = await this.page.request.post(url, {  
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer token'
            }, 
            data: requestBody
            
        }) 

        expect(response.status()).toBe(statusCode)
        return(response)
    }
}


You can get the token, and set the extra header every POST call instead of static token.
Demo
Using keycloak v24 and get access token and create user with access token.
1 Launch Keycloak
In here by docker-compose
2 Install playwrite and dependency
npm install -D @playwright/test
npx playwright install

3 Create Files
/root of your test directory
|-- api/
|   |-- apiRequests.js
|
|-- tests/
|   |-- apiTest.test.js
|
|-- playwright.config.js

api/apiRequests.js
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

class ApiRequests {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    async postRequest(url, requestBody, expectedStatusCode) {
        const response = await this.page.request.post(url, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: requestBody
        });

        expect(response.status()).toBe(expectedStatusCode);
        return response;
    }

    async getToken(url, formBody, expectedStatusCode) {
        const response = await this.page.request.post(url, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: formBody
        });

        expect(response.status()).toBe(expectedStatusCode);
        const responseJson = await response.json();

        return responseJson.access_token; // Return only the access token
    }
}

module.exports = { ApiRequests };

tests\apiRequests.js
const { test: baseTest, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { ApiRequests } = require('../api/apiRequests');

// Define a base test fixture to include setting headers
const test = baseTest.extend({
    authHeaders: async ({ page }, use) => {
        const apiReq = new ApiRequests(page);
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token';
        const formBody = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin',
            client_id: 'admin-cli'
        };

        const accessToken = await apiReq.getToken(url, new URLSearchParams(formBody).toString(), 200);
        await use({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        });
    },
});

test.describe('API User Management Tests', () => {
    test('POST API Test for User Creation', async ({ page, authHeaders }) => {
        page.context().setExtraHTTPHeaders(authHeaders);

        const apiReq = new ApiRequests(page);
        const userUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/users';

        // Data for the new user
        const userData = {
            username: "user1",
            emailVerified: true,
            email: "user1@example.com",
            firstName: "Super",
            lastName: "Mario",
            enabled: true
        };

        // Attempt to create user
        const createResponse = await apiReq.postRequest(userUrl, userData, 201);
        if (createResponse.status() === 409) {
            console.log("User already exists, test might need cleanup or handle existing user.");
        }

    });
});

playwright.config.js
module.exports = {
    testDir: 'tests',
    testMatch: '**/*.test.js',
};

4 Test
npx playwright test

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ok 1 apiTest.test.js:26:5 › API User Management Tests › POST API Test for User Creation (420ms)

  1 passed (1.1s)

5 Result
user1 is created

